# Mysql column duplicacy

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which none of the field is primary and autoincrement. There is a field 'uid' which is not autoincrement and not primary key. It have same values for each record. Now i want to create that field unique and autoincremented, but it have duplicacy in column.
So please suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: How can a column be unique and also have duplicates?  Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: can you drop this fields and add it after?

Comment: Either remove duplicate data first or just forgot to change it to unique column

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicates, Remove the rows?

Answer (score 1):

just add a unique constraint to the column and use the ignore keyword to ignore warnings/errors. Try this line:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (uid);
```

Then you can add the auto-increment as you normally would.